# SwiftUI custom tab bar: how to switch views when user drags finger across tab bar buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gesture

I have developed a custom tab bar ([ready to paste playground source](https://gist.github.com/tkafka/6504a7eee87c1f68e2a7bfee99658870)), but now, in addition to user tapping the buttons to switch views, I would like to be able to swipe finger over the tab bar, and have views activated as I'm dragging over the tab bar buttons.

I tried listening on `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)` on individual buttons.
This helps in activating the view on touch down instead of touch up (which is how default Button works), but will only activate the button where user started dragging.

I assume I would somehow need to add `.simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)` to the whole tab bar, and I could then probably interpret the touch coordinates against individual button hit tests.

However, this doesn't feel like the SwiftUI way - is there an easier way to let the SwiftUI do the heavy lifting?

(Please note - in playground, I now get `AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 2584` notices, and the actual selection lags one tap behind the last tapped button for some reason, but it works okay in Xcode project.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a best solution, but I:

1. Saved a frame in global coordinates in each button
2. Used `DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)` on a tab bar, to manually hit test each button
3. And disabled hit testing on individual buttons with `.allowsHitTesting(false)`, otherwise they would 'steal' the gesture.

[Here's a diff of changes](https://gist.github.com/tkafka/6504a7eee87c1f68e2a7bfee99658870/revisions#diff-116ea48dfc4f9cf620f8b2d418881fc4dc6efd01adb11eaf2801401f9cceea3b)